# calculating the stream function

Tags: multivariable-calculus, vector-analysis

Given that the flow is found incompressible (previous question [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3992702/check-for-incompressibility-in-sin-and-cos)), is the approach above the right way towards finding the stream function? given that:
$\mathbf{u}=\sin{x}\sin{y}\mathbf{i}+\cos{x}\cos{y}\mathbf{j}$

$$\tag{B}
\sin{x}\sin{y}=\frac{\partial\phi}{\partial y}\qquad \cos{x}\cos{y}=-\frac{\partial\phi}{\partial x}$$

I have thought of approaching it this way:

$\frac{\partial\phi}{\partial y}=\sin{x}\sin{y} = \int\sin{x}\sin{y}$ and integrating with respect to y:

1. $-\cos{y}\sin{x} + f(x)$ where f(x) is a constant of integration,  and substituting the second part of (B).
2. $\frac{\partial\phi}{\partial x}(-\cos{y}\sin{x} + f(x)) = -f'(x) ; f(x) =-\sin{x}\cos{y} + C $
3. Therefore when adding both integrated factors we get :   $\phi=-\cos{y}\sin{x}-\sin{x}\cos{y}$ where $\phi$ is a constant.

Which is equal to:
$-2\cos{y}\sin{x}?$ when we simplify the equation on the right-side on 3.

Comment: where did the 2 come from? And what is step 3 supposed to say, e.g. "therefore 0.7" is not a full sentence

Comment: @CalvinKhor Does it make better sense? I tend to overly simplify things by habit.

Comment: Yes, but I still do not see where the two came from, it should be $\phi = ... + f(x) = ... + g(y)$, then you should get that $f=g=0$, which leaves no way to get a 2?

Comment: in addition, you can very easily differentiate your guess for $\phi$ and see if it works

Comment: Could you possibly show me in the answers, I'm failing to understand you comment

Comment: Not sure what difference it makes, but I have posted it as an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Step one gives you

$$ \phi(x,y) = -\cos y\sin x+f(x)$$
for some $f(x)$,
and step two gives
$$ \phi(x,y) = -\cos y\sin x+g(y),$$
for some $g(y)$. These are both correct.

It does not follow that $\phi$ is constant, i.e. your step 3 is wrong. Instead, combine the first two steps, and you should see $f\equiv0\equiv g$. (get some paper and actually write it out carefully, if it is not clear.)

You can check by direct computation that your guess for $\phi$ is wrong: Well, firstly, $\phi$ is not a constant, and neither is $-2\cos y \sin x$, but if you meant to say that

$$\phi(x,y)=-2\cos y \sin x$$

then just differentiate in either $x$ or $y$ to see that you have an extra factor of $2$.

Comment: That clears things up!